# Search multiple cells in Excel, w/ example

Tags: excel, formula, cells

I appreciate the responses, but I think my wording was ambiguous.  Let me try to explain with a picture instead.

http://postimg.org/image/mrh7okefp/

The formula is put in C2 and will look at all the words in A2.  Then it will search B2:B9 for any matches.  If it finds something, it will put that word in C2.  If it finds nothing, it leaves the cell blank (I forgot to include this in the image). The formula can then be dragged down to C3 and will search the same B2:B9, putting the found word in C3.  So on and so forth.  Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Can there be multiple words in the text? For example, can there be a text with `dog cat mouse green orange table`? If so, how should the formula handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Alt+F11, paste this code into an empty module, at Tools/References check VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 checkbox and use ExtractColor as a User Defined Function in column B. It handles cells with more than one keywords.

```
Function ExtractColor(c As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .ignorecase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(red)|(blue)|(orange)|(green)|(black)|(white)|(purple)|(yellow)|.+?"
        Set myMatches = .Execute(c)
        If .Test(c) Then ExtractColor = Application.Trim(.Replace(c, "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8"))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This worked, though apparently if you go higher than $99, the function won't cooperate any more.  At least it didn't for me.  I created several of the functions with all of the key terms I needed and combined them into one column in Excel afterward

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using a formula. Imagine a set up as follows:

```
    A                            B
1   dog cat mouse orange table
2   cat                          cat
3   orange                       orange
4   bananas                      No match
```

In cell `B2` enter this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1,1),LEN(A2))),"No match",MID($A$1,FIND(A2,$A$1,1),LEN(A2)))
```

This works by checking if there is a match. If there is, it gets the position of the first character together with the length of the word to extract what you need.

A couple of points:

1. You may want to think about how to handle case sensitivity
2. This works if there is only one instance of the search word in the sentence

Hopefully this helps get you started.

Comment: If that's the requirement you could do that more easily with this formula `=IF(COUNTIF(A$1,"*"&A2&"*"),A2,"No match")`......but shouldn't "cat" be a match?

Comment: @barry - yes, that is a much more succinct (elegant!) formula. I like it (+1). And `cat` should match - i'll amend my typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The formula can be further simplified to get the searched text in the cell. In the table below are the texts searched for and their presence found:

```
1 dog cat mouse orange table    

         A           B  
    3 cat   FOUND
    4 orange    FOUND
    5 grapes    NOT FOUND
    6 table FOUND
    7 red   NOT FOUND
    8 dine      NOT FOUND
    9 table FOUND
    10 dog  FOUND
    11 cat  FOUND
    12 leg      NOT FOUND
```

I have put the following formula in Cell B3 and dragged it down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A9,$A$1,1)>0),"NOT FOUND","FOUND")
```